# jQuery menu and sub-menu delay

Tags: jquery, menu, delay

I have a sub-menu system that is written in jQuery. It works well but I want there to be a slight delay in hiding the Sub Menu options when the mouse moves off a "Top Menu" option. This is in order to give the user time to mouse over and select an option on the sub menu. At present the user sometimes misses making a sub-menu selection.

I have created a JS fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/K2tub/2/

I think the changes have to be made on line 90:

```
$('ul.fixture-list').slideUp(10);
```

I have been playing with this for nearly 2 hours but cannot get the sub-menu hide to be delayed.

Thanks in advance,

Alan.

Comment: or simply add .delay() like $('ul.fixture-list').delay(100).slideUp(10); [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Comment: @BuDen - I already tried the delay() function, but it doesn't delay the sub menu hide, instead it delays the display of the sub-menu... doesn't make any sense!

Answer (score 1):

see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K2tub/15/)

and use [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```
  $('ul.fixture-list').delay(500).slideUp(10);
```

Comment: thanks I tried using delay but it doesn't work. I tried your demo, if you hover over 'main option 4', then mouse off the 'option 2' disappears instantly...

Comment: I am also using chrome, i think the problem is being caused by line 67: '$('ul.fixture-list').removeAttr('style')' - this line is important becuase i have to reset the height of any previously displayed sub menu - such as the height. If I comment out this line the delay works for me in chrome

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the hoverIntent plugin : http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js

Here is a few docs : http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Your biggest problem here is that your sub-menu is not wrap in the parent menu element, so when you're pointing to your sub-menu, the 'parent' menu call the 'mouse-out' event and won't stay open.

Here is an example of something that should work if you had a sub-menu wrapped by the parent menu in the HTML :

http://jsfiddle.net/K2tub/22/

```
$('#nav').hoverIntent({
    over: function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);
    },
    out: function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(10);
        $('ul.fixture-list').removeAttr('style');
    },
    selector: 'li.matches',
    timeout: 500,
    interval: 10
});

$('#nav li.matches li').hoverIntent({
    over: function () {
        $('div.fixtures').empty();
        $('div.fixtures').prepend('<li>Optinon 2</li>');
        $('ul.fixture-list').slideDown(50);
    },
    out: function () {
        $('ul.fixture-list').slideUp(10);
    },
    selector: 'a.leagueSelect',
    timeout: 500,
    interval: 100
});
```

(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: @Olibo50 Thank you, I have tested your fiddle, if you mouse over Main Option 2-4 the sub menu appears and disappears so it's not quite working correctly. The sub-menu options should disappear until the mouse moves off the 'Main Options' menu.

Comment: What is most puzzling is why this line causes the delay not to work: $('ul.fixture-list').removeAttr('style');

Comment: @AlanA Yes, it doesn't work properly. That's why i suggest you to rebuild your HTML. It could be a lot easier if your sub-menu list was inside each parent menu item.

Comment: I don't quite understand... inside EACH parent menu? Do you mean that the 'fixtures' wrapper should also include the manin menu options?